# Steps for running modded firmware on Android Emulator

Tags: android

I wish to run the following [modded firmware](http://www.androidfanatic.com/community-forums.html?func=view&catid=9&id=2245) on the android emulator. 
Is there a tutorial for doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

Those over-2-year-old modded ROMs are for the T-Mobile G1 and the ADP1. Those are physical devices, not the emulator. You will need a modded ROM for the emulator to run it on the emulator, AFAIK.

Please contact the developer of whatever ROM you are seeking for further assistance.